# タグ「winapi」と「win32api」のマージを提案します

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[winapi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)と[win32api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32api)は同一のものを指しており、マージされるべきと思います。

ちなみに以前はWin32 APIと呼ばれていましたが、現在は[Windows API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/api-index-portal#win32-windows-api)と呼ばれています。
また、Stack Overflow本家では [`winapi`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/synonyms) を主として

- `windows-api`
- `win32`
- `win32api`
- `window-api`
- `windows-sdk`

が別名に登録されています。
日本語版においても同様になるよう、[winapi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)の別名として[win32api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32api)が設定されることを提案します。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

特に反対意見や票もなく、十分なプラス票が集まっているようなので [winapi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) をメインのタグとして "win32api" を別名に設定、マージしておきました。

---

念の為の補足として、別名の提案は信用度 1,250 以上、アクティブになるには投票スコアが 4 点以上になればいいようです。

**参考:**
[タグの別名の作成 - ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: [スコア5以上のユーザーが5人以上いるタグ](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1404220/55) ってほとんどなくて、別名の提案は実質機能していないんですよね…。

Comment: 頻度は高くないので今回の方法 (メタに投稿) でも問題ないと思いますが、必要ならベータ版を抜けるまでしきい値を下げてもらうよう掛け合ってみるのも一つの方法かもしれません。

Comment: そうかもしれませんが、スコア５も５人の同意も適切なバランスが考慮された結果でしょうから、変えるべきか悩むところです。まずは１つずつ討議として提案することにします。